# How to vertically align logo and menu in Foundation?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have a simple top-bar using Foundation that is coded up like this..

```
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="default.html"><img src="http://dev.golightlyplus.com/wig/website/images/wig-logo.png" alt="Home"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The codepen for it is [here](http://codepen.io/magician11/pen/mVBvaY).

What I'm wanting to do is vertically align the right menu with the middle of the logo. I can apply a margin above the top-bar-right class.. but is there a smarter way to do this in Foundation 6?

Would using something like [Equalizer](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/equalizer.html) make sense here?

Thanks.

Comment: My link was incorrect. Please check now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working [demo.](http://codepen.io/tarun-dugar/pen/rxGRjK)

First, set the `position` of `top-bar` to be `relative`.

```
.top-bar {
    position: relative;
}
```

Then, set the position of `.menu` in `top-bar-right` to `absolute` and use transform:

```
.top-bar-right .menu {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure whether this should be a new question.. but when I add a dropdown your method breaks it. http://codepen.io/magician11/pen/gPvNOd Thoughts? Just doing something like `margin-top: 18px;` for `.top-bar-right .menu` works.